# What does President Obama's joke, "Bucket taking executive action on immigration," "Bucket new climate regulation" mean?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

There were the following lines in President Obama’s speech delivered in the White House Correspondents’ Dinner held on April 25 at the Washington Hilton Hotel:

> “Just this week, Michele Bachmann predicted I would bring about the
>   biblical end of days. Now that’s a legacy. - - I am determined to make
>   the most of every moment I have left.  After the midterm elections, my
>   advisors asked me “Mr. President, do you have a bucket list?” And I
>   said, “Well, I have something that rhymes with bucket list.” Take
>   executive action on immigration. **Bucket.** New climate regulations.
>   **Bucket.** It’s the right thing to do.”

I heard the word, “bucket” being used in this way for the first time. Does it mean “to keep” something in a priority to do-list, or just "Forget it"?

Is it a common usage of “bucket” as a verb (here in imperative form), or is it usable in this way only in connection with “bucket list”?

Comment: I'm not sure you can really describe that as a *verb* usage. I'd say it's more of an *exclamation* (or "shorthand" for imperative *Stick that in your [bucket list!*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bucket+list)). Or just exclaiming *Essential!* But if people want to extend the usage and make it a "true" verb, I don't see the problem, since English allows virtually *any* word to be "verbified" (assuming it's understood by the audience/readership).

Comment: The key piece is this: "I have something that **rhymes** with bucket list." I will discreetly allow you to imagine what interjection rhymes with "Bucket."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The hidden meaning appears more clearly in the *[audio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cyUXUTaYAaw)* version.

*[Bucket list](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/bucket-list)*:

> noun
>
> informal A number of experiences or achievements that a person hopes
>   to have or accomplish during their lifetime:
>
> *making this trip is the first thing on my bucket list*

Metaphoric application to things you would like to accomplish before the end of your second term as president:

> “Mr. President, do you have a *bucket list*?”

So what ***rhymes*** with *bucket list*?

> F#@k it list!

This is a play on words based on the implication of a vivid imagination:

> Take executive action on immigration.
>   [Rhymes with] *Bucket*.
>   New climate regulations.
>   [Rhymes with] *Bucket*.

Comment: I'm not still clear with your explanation. What "does F#@%" represent for?

Comment: Profanity does require a bit of cultural connection, and this level of profanity still remains objectionable to many native English speakers.

Comment: So much for the dignity of the office.

Comment: One does need to keep in mind that the White House Correspondents' Dinner is traditionally an event where much humor is displayed.

Comment: @Oishi, if you google "the F word," you will find what you want to know.  urbandictionary.com will definitely help you. Be advised, it's one of the most offensive words in English -- which is why nobody here is willing to say it.

Comment: There's no need to dance around it; Obama is saying he has a "Fuck it" list, which means, it's a "I don't give a shit about it anymore" list. But it's a **joke**. He's the Chief Executive. He tried to do something positive about immigration and climate change, and was opposed in Congress. Now that he's running his term out, he can say, "Fuck it, at least I tried." That's his "fuck it" list. It's a funny, sarcastic comment on the problems he's faced in office.

Comment: I think the OP didn't recognize the *symbols* representing the expletive. It's been edited now. The convention of using punctuation or exclamation marks is  typically used in literature, the reader understands a vulgar or taboo word or words  are being expressed. Another convention is saying or writing "The F word" or writing "f**k it"

Comment: @EdMiller - are you one of these "Thanks, Obama" people? If you want to cite lack of dignity, look at Clinton. Obama is pristine in comparison to some of the people who've sullied the Office.

Comment: @Mari-Lou. Thanks for your help as usual. I didn’t realize “bucket” means ”f--k it” at all though ScotM hinted it in his answer. I took it quite contrary, because it was followed by “It’s the right thing to do,” which I took both of the executive action on immigration and new climate regulations are the  key tasks to be marked down in his bucket list as his life work. It seems I was totally wrong. BTW can I slang “bucket it” in the same way as “f--k it / them” to my subordinate when he brings up a sloppy business plan for my review, as Mr. Obama said?

Comment: No, not yet in any case. It could catch on if people start using *bucket* [just the one word: **b(f)uck + (i)et**] as a minced oath kind of thing, but without any context (I know something that rhymes with *bucket* [list]) people will probably respond with an "eh?" Also see StoneyB's comment.

Comment: Come to think of it, if you were to say out loud *bucket* native speakers will probably assume you were saying "fuckit", it does sound very similar, and maybe used in the right context, you're frustrated, annoyed by something or somebody, and if you stress the -b sound then people will understand what you mean. I'm not American, so I don't know if it has caught on, or if people are talking about Obama's (or his speech writers') clever pun. In any case "fuck it" IMO doesn't have half the baggage it used to carry.

Comment: @YoichiOishi I think what Obama was parading, comically, was his recent surge of defiance after the disastrous mid-term election: he had recently given up trying to work through Congress and taken unilateral action, and the effect was as if he had told Congress "You won't cooperate? Fuck it, I'm going ahead and doing it by myself."

Comment: @YoichiOishi - if you want a clean alternative to "Bucket" that will be understandable, you could replace it with "Trash it"

Comment: @Oldcat. I think so. It's better than "F--k it."

Comment: A politer alternative to the f-word that also rhymes with "bucket" might be "duck it" (ie. avoid it).

Comment: Yes, @MarkBannister, except Mr. Obama does not propose avoiding these issues, rather advancing them. He's not using the expression to say, "I don't care about these issues." He's using it to say to his opposition: "FU! I'll just pursue my agenda without you."

Comment: @ScotM - From the rest of the quotation, it looks as though you are right. It's surprising to me, because in my experience when someone says "F- it", what they normally mean is "I don't care about it".

Comment: @MarkBannister, the referent to the pronoun *it* seems to be the implied *public opinion* or *political opposition*, both of which a lame duck President has the luxury of ignoring.